# find a formula to find best approximation to a number using a collection of numbers

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to find a formula to find best approximation to a number using a collection of  numbers.

for example i have a collection of numbers like:`2,5,2,25,4,50`

I am trying to fit them to make  `270` using such operators like `+,-,*`.

I think the best fit is :`50*5+25-4=271` or maybe better.

so my question is: what is the fastest way to find best fit?

is there a formula or a interesting way to do it fast?

Comment: For small collections of numbers like this, computer program using brute force would be fastest though not interesting.

Comment: @John Habert i think  brute force just generate numbers but can not  operate on numbers. i wrote one app but it have not good result.do you have a link?

Comment: I don't have a link but I am sure it could be done. With $6$ numbers and $3$ operations, it would do $6!*3^5 = 174960$ computations. Track which is closest to $270$ and record what choices were used to get it.

Comment: @John Habert that is a good idea i ll try it

Comment: if you can use parenthesis, it will be much more

but you can still do it in $6!∗4^5$ if you add an operator to treat both $a-b$ and $b-a$ and if you forgot priorities.

Comment: Bilou06 has a good point about grouping. Is that allowed? I assumed that this was a left-to-right style calculation as is often used in puzzles.

Comment: @John Habert yes i can use i will try it

Comment: Do you have to use all the numbers? If not, then you can do $(2+25)*2*5=270$ in your example above. Again, being able to ignore certain numbers increases the number of calculations. We are now talking about something on the order of $2^{26}$ calculations (which still isn't a lot for modern computers).

Comment: @ John Habert i have to use all of them

Comment: So for the above you can use $((4-2)+(50-25))*2*5=270$.

Comment: @ John Habert yes you are right,i am trying to write it's program